# Redirection Module in a JSP/Servlet web application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, redirect

Well, I need help creating a redirection module for a java web application. Its based on jsp/servlets.

Functionalities of the module:
 - If a user enters a link of the webpage and the user isn't logged in,  the app should ask the user to login first and only then redirect the user to the specified link.

I have achieved this functionality, but done it by storing those links in session, some overhead codes on each jsp pages, which is kind of really unmanaged. Could you suggest ideas or APIs which could be useful in creating such module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at JAAS, the [Java Athentication and Authorization Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service). This is a service that the container (Tomcat, Wildfly, ...) provides to you, and abstracts this concern, so that your application doesn't needs to implement the security model from scratch.

You can find the reference guide [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider spring security. This mechanism is already implemented there. You are only declaring, which URLs are being protected by `FilterSecurityInterceptor` (for example by regexp), no need for coding in JSPs.